# Angular Material - row with two columns horizontal alignment

Tags: html, css, angular-material

I have a row with two columns. I want to keep second column all the way to the right.
I use a gap between two columns to push second column to the right. I tried this:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="calc(100% - 10px)">
   <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="400px"></div>
   <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="300px"></div>
</div>
```

When the Browser is at 100% it looks right, but when I zoom in the second column starts moving to the right but instead, I want a gap to start getting smaller. Is it possible to do that?

TIA

Comment: Angular decided to deprecate Flex-Layout. You can achieve what you want using CSS only. If you can create a reproducible effect online and share it maybe people will be able to help